# JSON Key Value Pairs within an Array in PHP using the json_encode() Function

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get my JSON output in a particular syntax

here is my code:

```
$ss = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg');
$dates = array('eu' => '59.99', 'us' => '39.99');
$array1 = array('name' => 'game1', 'publisher' => 'ubisoft', 'screenshots' => $ss, 'dates' => $dates, 'added' => '2014/12/31');

echo json_encode($array1);
```

it gives me this output:

```
{
name: "game1",
publisher: "ubisoft",
screenshots: [
"1.jpg",
"2.jpg"
],
dates: {
eu: "59.99",
us: "39.99"
},
],
added: "2014/12/31"
}
```

which is CLOSE but, not exactly what I need. The dates need to be formatted slightly different. Like this:

```
{
name: "game1",
publisher: "ubisoft",
screenshots: [
"1.jpg",
"2.jpg"
],
dates: [
{
eu: "59.99"
},
{
us: "39.99"
}
],
added: "2014/12/31"
}
```

I have tried adding more dimensions to the $dates array, but that still doesn't give quite the right output. Unfortunately the php manual for the json_encode() function doesn't provide much help and there is very little documentation on more complex json encodes within php that i have found with google searching.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the actual JSON. Your brackets aren't balanced.

Comment: Why do you want objects with different keys in the `dates:` array? Won't that make it difficult to access the values, since you don't know the key?

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks for your quick reply. Sorry, I have edited the desired output. It was hand typed and I got it wrong. Also, a friend of mine who works with Json has given me a very specific specification of how he wants the Json to read. I know almost nothing about Json or why he needs it the way he does, so I'm actually quite surprised I've even made it this far!

Comment: The original output also has mismatched brackets. There's no opening `[` for the closing `]` above `added:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `$dates` assignment to:

```
$dates = array(array('eu' => '59.99'), array('us' => '39.99'));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply and help with this :)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do something like this ( wrap each date in its own assoc array)

```
array( 
   array('eu' => '59.99'),
   array('us' => '39.99')
);
```

Then it will encode correctly as

```
[
   {'eu' : '59.99'},
   {'us' : '39.99'}
]
```

It's simple really, arrays with numeric( natural ) keys are just `[ ]`, associative arrays are `{ key : value }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ss = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg');
$dates[] = array('eu' => '59.99');
$dates[]=array('us' => '39.99');
$array1 = array('name' => 'game1', 'publisher' => 'ubisoft', 'screenshots' => $ss, 'dates' => $dates, 'added' => '2014/12/31');
echo json_encode($array1);
```